# Getting a ClassCastException on Executing a SPARQL Query in Apache Jena.?

Tags: java, sparql, apache-jena

I'm new to using Apache Jena!
Following is my code. Exception at exec.execSelect(),can anyone tell why?

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString(""
                + "prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"
                + "PREFIX dbo:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"
                + "\n"
                + "select distinct ?resource ?abstract where {\n"
                + "  ?resource rdfs:label 'Ibuprofen'@en.\n"
                + "  ?resource dbo:abstract ?abstract.\n"
                + "  FILTER (lang(?abstract) = 'en')}");


        QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", qs.asQuery());

        ResultSet results = exec.execSelect();

        while (results.hasNext()) {

            System.out.println(results.next().get("abstract").toString());
        }

        ResultSetFormatter.out(results);
    }
```

And the Exception is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer    at
>   org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams.getIntParameter(AbstractHttpParams.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParamConfig.getRequestConfig(HttpClientParamConfig.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:806)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:139)
>     at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.exec(HttpOp.java:1097)   at
>   org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpGet(HttpOp.java:378)  at
>   org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpGet(HttpOp.java:440)  at
>   org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:345)
>     at
>   org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:337)
>     at trial.SecondAttempt.main(SecondAttempt.java:32)

Comment: (which version?) The exception indicates that some code has set an HttpClient HttpParams but it is not clear where from.  Are you setting ARQ.serviceParams?

Comment: You have a conflict in your project with some other libs. Jena uses an older HTTP API version. But we need to know which other libs you have in your classpath resp. which other dependencies you have in your Maven project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434799/jena-sparql-error-java-lang-integer

Comment: Thanks alot @AKSW. There were conflicts with other libs in Maven!